# Dynamic SQL query to get all the items from two dates and count?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a dynamic SQL query that gets ID's from the previous dates and today's date and prints it out. Also in a separate column, it should print the total count of the ids.

The problem I'm having with my query is that it's only printing the current dates ids and not the previous dates. I want it to print previous's dates ids to today's dates and on a separate column print Total Id's for today.

```
select Gid,created_time,count(Gid) AS total ID from GLog where created_time between 
to_char(current_date -1)||' 
5.00.00.000000000 PM' AND current_date||' 4.59.59.999999999 PM' and msg_type='CandyStore'
```

[This is an example of what the table should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTiNh.png)
My query should print ID's from yesterday's date all the way up to today's date and the total count in a separate column.

Comment: The part "*it should print the total count of the ids*" seems to contradict the part "*print Total Id's for today*" do you want the total count for all ids matching the WHERE condition or just those for today? It's also unclear if you want to group the result based on today's date or not (which the `count(gid)` would require)

Answer (score 0):

`current_date||' 4.59.59.999999999 PM'` makes no sense to begin with because  `current_date` already contains a time part. If you want to create a date/time with today's date but a fixed time. As this implicitly converts `current_date` to a varchar value depending on the current NLS settings the outcome is also not deterministic.

`to_char(current_date)` has the same problem, because it also depends on the current NLS settings.

Both expressions are likely to return something different on my computer than on yours (even if we connect to the same Oracle server). Plus: you are comparing a DATE column to a string value which isn't a good thing to begin with.

It would be better to ditch the BETWEEN operator in Oracle altogether (when comparing DATE or TIMESTAMP values) and use `>=` and `<` conditions instead.

so something like:

```
where 
  -- after yesterday at midnight
  created_time => trunc(sysdate - 1)
  -- and before today at 16:00
  and created_time < to_date(to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' 16:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
  and msg_type = 'CandyStore'
```

So `to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' 16:00'` creates a formatted representation of today's date at 16:00,  which is then converted to proper DATE value using `to_date()` again using a known format. Thus we can compare the created_time column with a proper DATE value (rather than a string).

By using `<` rather than `<=` (which BETWEEN implies) you can make the hour part a lot shorter as you don't need to find a value that is as close to 16:00 as possible.

If you prefer 12 hour formats, you can adjust the above code to use that.

**Edit**

Gordon is right, the above can be simplified to:

```
where created_time => trunc(sysdate - 1)
  and created_time < trunc(current_date) + interval '16' hour
  and msg_type = 'CandyStore'
```

Comment: Interesting.  I would use:  `trunc(sysdate) + interval '16' hour` rather than going back and forth to strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you are absolutely right. When I wrote it, I was frustrated that a simple `current_date + time '16:00'` doesn't work in Oracle and I was stuck mentally in the `to_char()` jungle. But obviously using an interval serves the same purpose and is much easier to understand